# Mojave: Generate SSH key with old private key format

Tags: terminal, ssh

After I fresh installed Mojave, when I generate a new SSH key it uses the new **OpenSSH protocol 2** format private key.

The `ID_RSA` file starts with "BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY", even if I run `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my@email.com"`

According to the ssh-keygen main page, the BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY file type is generated by specifying either the -o  command line option or creating an **ed25519** key type.

How can I create a private key using the **old format?**

Comment: If I remember correctly, protocol 2 has been the default since 2014/2015.  I know it's the default in El Cap and beyond (and I believe it was in Yosemite as well) - in other words, I don't see this as a Mojave issue.  Secondly, `rsa1` is version 1 and `ed25519` is version 2...Also using `-o' *forces* the new format...so it seems like you've got a mismatch going on there.

Comment: Also in the man page:  *Ed25519 keys always use the new private key format.*  So, you can't create a `ed25519` key with the old format.

Comment: @Allan Sorry for the delay. I understand. So, is it possible to generate a `rsa1` private key in Mojave? I need this kind of key because is the only accepted in MongoDB Compass – they don't accept new format key yet